# Convert IEnumerable to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq

I am very new to `IEnumerable` and I believe Linq. I have been researching how to convert `IEnumerable` to JSON. I saw the posting here: [How do I convert an IEnumerable to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827791/how-do-i-convert-an-ienumerable-to-json). I tried the solution and it did not work for me.

I received the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable' An explicit conversion  exists (are you missing a cast?

The code I am using is:

```
var displayedOrganizations = filteredOrganizations.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);

IEnumerable<Organization> result = from c in displayedOrganizations
                                   select new Organization[] { 
new Organization { ID = Convert.ToString(c.ID),CURR_PDD = c.CURR_PDD,NEW_PDD = c.NEW_PDD,CURR_OFFC = c.CURR_OFFC,NEW_OFFC = c.NEW_OFFC,
    CURR_DIV = c.CURR_DIV, NEW_DIV = c.NEW_DIV, CURR_BRANCH = c.CURR_BRANCH, NEW_BRANCH = c.NEW_BRANCH,CURR_DEPT = c.CURR_DEPT,NEW_DEPT = c.NEW_DEPT,
    CURR_DEPT_NAME = c.CURR_DEPT_NAME,NEW_DEPT_NAME = c.NEW_DEPT_NAME,ACTION = c.ACTION,USERID = c.USERID,UPDATED = c.UPDATED
}};
```

If I use the original code:

```
var displayedOrganizations = filteredOrganizations.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
var result = from c in displayedOrganizations
             select new[] { 
    Convert.ToString(c.ID), c.CURR_PDD, c.CURR_OFFC, c.CURR_DIV,c.CURR_BRANCH, c.CURR_DEPT, c.CURR_DEPT_NAME, 
    c.NEW_PDD, c.NEW_OFFC, c.NEW_DIV,  c.NEW_BRANCH, c.NEW_DEPT, c.NEW_DEPT_NAME, c.ACTION, c.USERID, c.UPDATED 
};
```

I get the following output:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":9,"iTotalDisplayRecords":9,"aaData":[["cb9f927f-0f2e-4a5e-898b-304e4e8518fd","MS","OHR"]]}
```

I am trying to get this output instead. I want a name/value pair instead of the value only.

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":9,"iTotalDisplayRecords":9,"aaData":[["ID":"cb9f927f-0f2e-4a5e-98b-304e4e8518fd","DIR":"MS","OFFC":"OHR"]]}
```

I don't understand the code enough to make the changes. I got it from another site and it works perfectly except for the modification I am trying to make.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
IEnumerable<Organization> result =
```

to

```
var result =
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message makes the problem clear:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<Organization[]>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<Organization>'
```

You're trying to convert a *list of arrays of organizations* into a *list of organizations.*

Your `select` should be selecting the entries you want in the output. Don't wrap each `select` in an array -- instead of `select new Organization[] { new Organization { ... }}`; just select the objects: `select new Organization { ... }`.

```
IEnumerable<Organization> result =
    from c in displayedOrganizations
    select new Organization { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var displayedOrganizations = filteredOrganizations.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
IEnumerable<Organization> result = ...
```

to:

```
var displayedOrganizations = filteredOrganizations.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
IEnumerable<Organization[]> result = ...
```